# How to check data content inside $.post function?

Tags: jquery

```
$.post(
    $("#formReg").attr("action"), $("#formReg").serialize(),
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#info").html(data);
        alert (data); // to check - ok - `folder` is displaying
        if ($("#info").html() == "folder"){
        $("#imgOk").fadeIn();  //doesn't work
        }
});
```

Seems like `#info` has another content and not `folder`, although is checked by alert, and `folder` is visible on screen as the content.

Comment: Did you check for whitespace? Try `if ($("#info").html().trim() == "folder"){...`

Comment: Why not just check if (data ==  "folder") { ....fade in }

Comment: @adeneo, thanks. It works. But where are the spaces come from ? Anyway, place your comment as answer, pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when doing ajax requests, you'll have code on the server that inserts whitespace in the returned results. It's not always easy to see where the whitespace is added, but it could be a space before or after the code, like having a single space before `<?php` in PHP etc.

The best thing would be to simply remove the space on the serverside, but javascript also has a trim method that will trim following and trailing whitespace from a string:

```
if ($("#info").html().trim() == "folder"){...}
```

That function is not supported in older browsers, so if that's an issue you can use a regex, or since you're already using jQuery you can use a similar cross browser function, and it actually uses the same native `trim()` method in newer browsers, and regex in older browsers, so you don't have to worry about it:

```
$.post($("#formReg").attr("action"), $("#formReg").serialize(), function(data) {
    $("#info").html(data);
    if ($.trim(data) == 'folder') $("#imgOk").fadeIn();
});
```